# In-memory caching of password across Powershell cmdlet invocations

Tags: powershell, security, session, passwords

I have some custom cmdlets that each require a user name and password to execute. At the moment I have to enter my credentials each and every time I run any of these cmdlets. The usage pattern is such that I typically run different combinations of these commands within a short window of time, maybe once every couple days. This means I have to enter my password several times within this short period.

Is there any way I can tell Powershell to cache the credentials in-memory for some period of time? I realize this is a security trade-off, but it's one I'm willing to make, especially considering the password is stored as a `SecureString`. If there was some kind of persistent "session" object in which I could store data across cmdlet invocations, that would also work, but I've been unable to identify such a feature.

**UPDATE**

I forgot to mention I'm targetting .NET core and have been unable to use the `PSCredential` type. I have this in my base cmdlet class:

```
[Parameter(
    Mandatory = true,
    HelpMessage = "Credentials for access.",
    ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true)]
public PSCredential Credentials
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

But attempting to dereference the `Password` property gives a compiler error:

```
Reference to type 'SecureString' claims it is defined in 'mscorlib', but it could not be found  Contented.PowerShell..NETStandard,Version=v1.6
```

Relevant dependencies of my project are:

```
"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.5.ReferenceAssemblies": "1.0.0-*",
  "System.Security.SecureString": "4.3.0"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$cred = Get-Credentials
```

And then pass `$cred` to the commands you are invoking. Or (if we are talking about PS Sessions). This way you can reuse session to invoke many commands.

```
$session = New-PSSession 
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, couldn't get `PSCredential` to work because I'm targetting .NET core. Forgot to mention that in question, sorry.

Comment: well, share your code or something, its completely unclear what the problem is now

Comment: Ugh, I've just figured out I need to use `Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK` instead of `Microsoft.PowerShell.5.ReferenceAssemblies`. Just gotta figure out how to configure NuGet to consume the MyGet feed...